# How to get screenshot of any Linux/Windows application running outside of the JVM

Tags: java, process, external, screenshot

Is it possible to use Java to get a screenshot of an application external to Java, say VLC/Windows Media Player, store it as an Image object and then display it in a JLabel or something of a similar nature? Does anybody know if this is possible and if so does anybody have a general idea as to how to do it?

Note: I just need to find out how to get a screenshot and store it as some form of Image object. After that I can use, manipulate it, display it, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is the answer for Windows** (not sure if alt+printScr works on linux :P)

I guess one way to achieve this

**1. using Robot class to fire alt+printScreen Command** (this captures active window to clipboard)

**2. read the clipboard!**

Here are the two pieces of code that do that. I have not actually tried, but something that I pieced together.

> Code to Fire commands to get active window on clipboard

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class ActiveWindowScreenShot
{
 /**
  * Main method
  * 
  * @param args (not used)
  */
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  Robot robot;

  try {
   robot = new Robot();
  } catch (AWTException e) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("No robot");
  }

  // Press Alt + PrintScreen
  // (Windows shortcut to take a screen shot of the active window)
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);

  System.out.println("Image copied.");
 }
}
```

> Code to read image on clipboard

```
// If an image is on the system clipboard, this method returns it;
// otherwise it returns null.
public static Image getClipboard() {
    Transferable t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents(null);

    try {
        if (t != null && t.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.imageFlavor)) {
            Image text = (Image)t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);
            return text;
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can manage the control as you need to! Let me know if this works for you. but this is certainly on my todo to try it out!

Comment: Wow! I never thought of doing this. Good work mate, I will try it for sure. Merry Christmas!

Comment: Merry Christmas! Please try and tell if it works! Some how 'cant be done in java' sounded too harsh to my ears! :P

Comment: Can't believe i didint think of this by the way how many frames per second can you get with this.

Comment: I'm a billion years late, but how do you actually launch this from another window ? When I launch this in cmd, it captures cmd !

Comment: One way to do that would be kind of how the "Grab" screen shot app that ships with mac does it. You launch the java app.  Prompt user to select the window to be screenshot, and execute the code on window focus change. To do this form command line, you can also just start a timer to give you a few seconds to select active window.

Answer (score 2):

You can get screen shot of whole screen using class named `Robot`. Unfortunately you cannot get location and size of windows that belong to other applications using pure java solution. To do this you need other tools (scripting, JNI, JNA). These tools are not cross-platform.

Comment: Thanks mate. Do you have any recommendations as far as being able to do what I want that is the fastest, easiest and most robust? I have a little C experience if that is of any use? I anxiously await your reply.

Comment: Hey why not give my answer a try! :P

Comment: @Alex: What do you think of my answer below?

Comment: @Shaunak, I think that your solution is nice but this code:                          `Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0, 0, d.width, d.height));` is simpler than dealing with clipboard.

Comment: And how would you get the screen position of active windows without using other tools as you mention in your answer?